# Build an encrypted Docker container via Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I have a pipeline in Azure DevOps that build a container and push it in my Azure Container Registry.

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'myguyd'
  imageRepository: 'p2005'
  containerRegistry: 'myacr.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/api/DOCKERFILE'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: latest
```

In the container I also have some raw data file that the application needs. In the security point of view, it is not great to have the raw data in the container.

So, I was thinking if there is a way to encrypt the Docker container. And if so, how to do it in the Azure pipeline.

Comment: do you mean you don't trust the docker registry? if yes, why do you trust auzre pipeline?

Comment: The problem is that the data is not protected. So, if someone has access to the Docker container, it can read the data. It is very unlikely but I have to protect the data.

Comment: you should seprate sensitive data outside docker completely, use environment variables, or k8s secrets, for example.

Comment: Have you ever tried Ramazan Kilimci's answer and Lei Yang's suggestions. If the answer is helpful, please mark it as a correct one. If not, we are happy to help you solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know there is a way to encrypt via the Azure pipeline. If you're using AKS by chance, you can take a look at [**Confidential Computing**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/confidential-computing/confidential-containers).

> A hardware-based Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) provides strong
> assurances. A TEE provides hardware and software measurements from
> trusted computing base (TCB) components. Confidential containers
> offerings on Azure allow verification of these measurements and
> validate if the container applications run in a verifiable execution
> environment.
>
> Confidential containers support custom applications developed with any
> programming languages. You can also run Docker containers off the
> shelf.

You can achieve this with Intel SGX and AKS.

> To run an existing Docker container, applications on confidential
> computing nodes require an abstraction layer or Intel Software Guard
> Extensions (SGX) software to use the special CPU instruction set.
> Configure SGX to protect your sensitive application code. SGX creates
> a direct execution to the CPU to remove the guest operating system
> (OS), host OS, or hypervisor from the trust boundary. This step
> reduces the overall surface attack areas and vulnerabilities.
>
> Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) fully supports confidential containers.
> You can run existing containers confidentially on AKS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For a variety of reasons, [link-only answers are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248627). Please edit your answer and include the main points directly in your question. See [answer].